# apache poi: change the font of existing entire sheet

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I has a existing workbook containing multiple sheets. I have a sheet which contains some bold cells in it. I want to change the font of this entire sheet retaining the boldness of some of the cells. Can you please provide me the code snippet?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to create more than one style for the workbook:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

XSSFCellStyle fontStyleBold = wb.createCellStyle();
XSSFCellStyle fontStyleNormal = wb.createCellStyle();
```

and assign the cells you want.